# Force closing a running dotnet process

Tags: windows, .net-core, windows-server, dotnet-cli

We are trying to have a CI/CD pipeline strategy which involves force closing/killing a running dotnet process which is running on our VisualCron server:

1. Turn off the VC Job
2. Force close/kill the process (????)
3. Deploy the latest assemblies
4. Restart the VC Job

The part that we are stuck on is that this VC server is running numerous jobs. In the past this wasn't an issue because a .NET Framework application was named appropriately 'somejob.exe'. However, with dotnet every process is running as dotnet.exe.

Is there a way to target a specific instance of a running dotnet.exe process to close/kill based on the entry point assembly passed into dotnet.exe? For example, `dotnet c:\jobs\somejob.dll` -- we need to close/kill just this job (not the other dotnet jobs running).

Comment: Is this *your* program? If so then instead of using `taskkill`, shouldn't you build in a way to cooperatively ask it to terminate gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to utilize the [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) tool to target a specific dotnet application, though the usage may vary based on the scenario.

In our scenario, our assemblies are named in a very unique fashion... All of our applications are namespaced out very well `CompanyName.ProductName.ConsoleAppName.dll`. This allows us to use the filter command and filter based on a specific module:

`taskkill /FI "Modules eq CompanyName.ProductName.ConsoleAppName.dll"`

---

Clearly, had our assemblies not been named in a unique fashion, this would not work well, for example, if we had our console app named *App.dll*.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a pretty solution, but it should do the trick.

So after doing a lot of reading, it seems this issue is known to the dotnet core team but isn't a priority (if they ever fix it).

Now I tried to do this without forcing you to install anything new to your computer but only rely on **cmd commands**

Step 1.

Start the process using START

```
> START "" cmd.exe /C dotnet <mydll> <MyUniqueIdentifier>
```

Ex.

```
> START "" cmd.exe /C dotnet HelloWorld.dll HelloWorldProgram
```

Step 2.

The below code can be run in a batch script to locate the Process ID of said program

```
@echo off
set DLL_NAME=HelloWorld.dll
set UNIQUE_ID=HelloWorldProgram
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('wmic process WHERE COMMANDLINE^="dotnet  %DLL_NAME% %UNIQUE_ID%" list full ^| findstr /I "^ProcessId"') DO (
    SET P=%%a
)
REM Here we have the Process ID
SET DNETP=%P:~10%

REM Terminate the proces
taskkill /PID %DNETP% /F
```